# Get geographical coordinates of a particular place from DbPedia

Tags: sparql, semantics, ontology, dbpedia

I need to get the co-ordinates of some particular places from DbPedia. For the same I am using following snippet:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
  SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x foaf:name 'Mumbai'.
  ?x dbo:Place 'Mumbai'.
  ?x geo:lat ?lat .
  ?x geo:long ?long .
  }
```

On running at http://dbpedia.org/sparql, it returns an empty page. I think I didn't put the name of place in the correct way. Can anyone help me to find the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [N3/TTL serialization of the data for Mumbai](http://dbpedia.org/data/Mumbai.n3).  Note that the **foaf:name** value has a language tag: **foaf:name "Mumbai"@en**. You need to use **"Mumbai"@en**, with the language tag, in the query.  Additionally, doing **dbo:Place 'Mumbai'** doesn't make any sense.  You might instead want to ask for things which *are* **dbpedia-owl:Places**.  You'd end up with a query like:

```sql
select * {
  ?mumbai a dbpedia-owl:Place ;
          foaf:name "Mumbai"@en ;
          geo:lat ?lat ;
          geo:long ?long
}
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fmumbai%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3APlace%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%22Mumbai%22%40en%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20geo%3Alat%20%3Flat%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20geo%3Along%20%3Flong%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)